# Difference in Javascript validation between Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Indigo

Tags: type-inference, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-indigo, jsdt

I've been experimenting with JSDT.

Under Indigo, the validation has stopped complaining about unknown fields of objects. In Helios, it does.

This is for all objects, as far as I can tell, but here's one example

I have a JSDT user library that among other things documents a log object.

```
log = function(){};
log.prototype = new Object();
log.debug = function(str){};
log.info = function(str){};
log.warn = function(str){};
log.error = function(str){};
```

And if I type

```
log.
```

into a Javascript editor, I get a completion list that includes info, warn etc.

If I continue and type

```
log.foobar()
```

in Helios, an error is detected and the message is about foobar not being known. This is good and what I want.

In Indigo, nothing. No error, it will happily accept any old garbage (I know that's what Javascript can do, but the point of JSDT is to do some inference and point out potential problems like this)

Is there some preference or option I've missed?

I do want to use Indigo since JSDT in Helios is more than a little buggy and I'm hoping Indigo is better.

Comment: the way i know about eclipse, the jsp editors might be different in both eclipse. If it is same, you can uninstall the one from Indigo and try to install the same version available in Helios. But the later case of having same plugin or editor is real less.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many dynamic ways for the foobar property to be added to the log object, and false positives can drown out real problems.  This was removed in Indigo.

Comment: OK, that's disappointing. It was really useful in our situation (server side Rhino largely used as glue for Java classes/methods). Now Eclipse really doesn't do much for our Javascript development. Can you point me to a list of changes where this removal (and ideally all other Indigo changes) is documented, or are we just supposed to guess :)